# Why does this sql query do a key lookup?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a table User with a bunch of indexes. One of them is a unique index on the AccountIdentifier column.

Since this is a unique index, why is a key lookup required in addition to the index seek? The index seek tooltip reports that only one record is returned. I've also tried converting the index to a "unique key" type.

[alt text http://s3.amazonaws.com/brandonc.baconfile.com/pitchurs/tmp/capture_2.png](http://s3.amazonaws.com/brandonc.baconfile.com/pitchurs/tmp/capture_2.png)

Comment: As an aside: never ever do a `SELECT *` on a production system - **NEVER** - no exceptions. This is bad practice to begin with....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because it is selecting `*`.

It uses the non clustered index to locate the row(s) but then needs to go and fetch the data to return.

To avoid the [bookmark lookup](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/bookmarklookups/1899/) you would need to make the non clustered index a covering index (ideally by reducing the number of columns in the select list but possible also by adding new columns into the index itself or as [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx))

If you have a clustered index on the table the row locator in the non clustered index will include the clustered index key so it won't need a bookmark lookup to satisfy queries on just the `AccountIdentifier` and clustered index columns.

Comment: I did some experimenting. So it would seem selecting anything not in the index used results in a key lookup. That makes sense.

Comment: @BC - Basically yes but if you have a clustered index you can consider those columns to be included automatically.

Answer (score 13):

Key lookup doesn't mean "look up the key", but "look up the row based on the key".

Answer (score 7):

See these articles and blog posts for some more background info on key lookups / bookmark lookups:

- [Showplan Operator of the Week - BookMark/Key Lookup](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/showplan-operator-of-the-week-bookmarkkey-lookup/)
- [Bookmark Lookups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/bookmark-lookup) by Craig Friedmann
- [Bookmark Lookups](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/bookmark-lookups) by Randy Dyess
- [Books Online on the Bookmark Lookup Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms180920%28v=sql.90%29)
- [SQL Server Query Optimization – Remove Bookmark Lookup](https://web.archive.org/web/20120901003809/http://sqlserverpedia.com:80/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-server-%E2%80%93-query-optimization-%E2%80%93-remove-bookmark-lookup-%E2%80%93-remove-rid-lookup-%E2%80%93-remove-key-lookup/)